# Quelle serait une façon plus élégante de dire « Au moment où j’écris cette ligne, j’en suis à mon deuxième verre de gin »?

Tags: formulation-idiomatique, reformulation

Là/Au moment où j’écris cette ligne, j’en suis à [boire] mon deuxième verre de gin.

C’est surtout la tournure « en être à » qui me fait hésiter sur son exactitude ou son admissibilité.

J’avais en tête « Je commence mon deuxième verre de gin à l’instant » ou « j’enchaîne avec mon deuxième verre de gin sur le moment». La première formulation me donne l’impression d’une banalité et la deuxième que j’entends à l’oral me laisse en proie au doute quant à son admissibilité à cause de « avec », qui ne semble pas d’un langage fort châtié ni même naturel.

Comment: ... je déguste/savoure mon deuxième verre ... | ... le gin de mon deuxième verre glisse sur/ humecte mes papilles. Il y a une quasi infinité de solutions pour changer le point de vue, celui du mental, celui des sensations, celui de l'environnement. Celui de l'objet considéré ...

Comment: @Personne Vu le passage du temps, peut-être que de verser ces quelques larmes et davantage en « community wiki » pourrait s'avérer un compromis acceptable pour vous ? Salut !